# How to change this code from switch case to if else?

Tags: java

How to use if-else to write this code?
I'd like to know the difference between the two methods. Thanks

```
switch (status) {
    case AIRCRAFT_CARRIER_HIT:
        if (this.getFleet().updateFleet(ShipType.ST_AIRCRAFT_CARRIER))
            result[1] = "a";
        break;
    case BATTLESHIP_HIT:
        if (this.getFleet().updateFleet(ShipType.ST_BATTLESHIP))
            result[1] = "a";
        break;
    case CRUISER_HIT:
        if (this.getFleet().updateFleet(ShipType.ST_CRUISER))
            result[1] = "a";
        break;
    case DESTROYER_HIT:
        if (this.getFleet().updateFleet(ShipType.ST_DESTROYER))
            result[1] = "a";
        break;
    case SUB_HIT:
        if (this.getFleet().updateFleet(ShipType.ST_SUB))
            result[1] = "a";
        break;
    default:
        result[1] = null;
```

Comment: Why would you want to? Both methods are good.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not really intended as a place to ask very basic questions about a given programming language (that is better learned by taking a class or reading a book).  This question also doesn't indicate very much effort to learn the answer yourself (please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: but thanks for your reminder, I will go check that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an if statement, the enum has to be in full form and the variable compared to has to be mentioned in all the conditions. I don't know the name of the enum, but I'll guess it's Status. In that case you'd write

```
if (status == Status.AIRCRAFT_CARRIER_HIT) {
    if (this.getFleet().updateFleet(ShipType.ST_AIRCRAFT_CARRIER)) {
        result[1] = "a";
    }
} else if (status == Status.BATTLESHIP_HIT) {
    // etc.
} else {
    result[1] = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your switch statement can be written as below with if/else (assuming the variables `AIRCRAFT_CARRIER_HIT` etc are **final** and assigned a value at compile time, eg `final int AIRCRAFT_CARRIER_HIT = 3` :

```
 if (status == AIRCRAFT_CARRIER_HIT ) {
       ...  
 }
 else if (status ==  BATTLESHIP_HIT) {
       ...  
 }
 …
 …
 else {
      // default case
 }
```

for differences and pros/cons of each approach you can check [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/switch-vs-else/)  for example

Comment: Assuming type of `status` is an enum, you need to qualify the enum values, as correctly done in [radulfr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58697305/5221149).